# Cannot switch branches in git

Tags: git

My question is about trying to switch branches in git. I keep getting the error message:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not rmdir 'C:/SourceGit/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/': Access is denied.

(those are not the actual names of the folders obvioulsy, had to swap out due to company policy and what not)

This usually occurs when I have uncommitted changes so I checked and it appears that I did. So I committed the changes that were necessary and undid those that were not and made sure the branch was clear of changes and the sync was complete and tried again and got the same message. Checking the changes again showed that the same changes I had just committed and undid were there again. I tried restarting my PC just in case and that didn't seem to fix it.

Not sure what else to try, any advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just try going to the folder and right click so there appears a menu
find out open git bash here  and click on it so the git will directly open the neccessary folder